# Find attribute having unicode string as value

Tags: jquery, unicode, svg

I need to traverse the following XML tree in order to find the glyph where `unicode=&#xf0c5;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <font>
        <glyph unicode="&#xf0c5;"/>
        <glyph unicode="&#xf005;"/>
    </font>
</svg>
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

**EDIT**

Maybe this wasn't clear but I want to access the glyphs by their values under `unicode` tag, because most of those printed characters will end up in ``.

I know that this is goin to work `$('svg').find('glyph[unicode=""]')`, but having:

```
if (cond1) {
    $('svg').find('glyph[unicode=""]');
} else if (cond2) {
    $('svg').find('glyph[unicode=""]');
} else {
    // ...
}
```

.. is something you'll never want to maintain.

Comment: Updated the answer, found another way

Comment: I think cutting the `&#x` and `;` and leaving the meaningful part of the string is an affordable trade-off, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

<strike>$('svg').find('glyph[unicode="&#xf0c5"]')</strike>

**Update**

I saw that the DOM changed after it loaded so you have to search after  so try this

```
 $('svg').find('glyph[unicode=""]')
```

**Update**

You can replace the &#x to \u and use that selector like this

```
&#xf0c5;==\uf0c5 //hex to Escaped Unicode
&#xf005;==\uf005
```

so the selector for the glyphs will be

```
if (cond1) {
    $('svg').find('glyph[unicode="\uf0c5"]');
} else if (cond2) {
    $('svg').find('glyph[unicode="\uf005 "]');
} else {
    // ...
}
```

**Note:** You don't need to update the html

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8LPz/4/)

Comment: @akoskm ah i checked the console saw that the attribute changed after dom ready. so i tried this and it actually worked :P `console.log($('svg').find('glyph[unicode=""]').attr('unicode'))` **DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/G8LPz/

Comment: what if I have 750x, how should my selector look like in my code, when I want '&#xf0c5;' or '&#xf005;', first time `find('glyph[unicode=""]')`, second time `find('glyph[unicode=""]')`? :)

Comment: @akoskm I've created a fiddle here to find both  '&#xf0c5;' and '&#xf005;' http://jsfiddle.net/G8LPz/3/ What you will have to do is look at the console and copy the unicode attribute from there to your selector to specify the element you want to search for. I don't know another way to do this :/ unless the position is static then you could use .eq()

Comment: thanks, most of those print will result in , I also edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's very messy :P hard to know which one you are selecting in the code, i'll look around and update the answer if i find another solution